# less -Sr colourful.log How to view colourful log in less?

Tags: linux, terminal, less, colors

Both `less -r` (preserve terminal control sequences) and `less -S` (chop long lines) work well alone. But using them together breaks things. It chops too late and it wrecks the next line.

Reducing COLUMNS environment variable is no op: (man less)

> But if you have  a windowing  system  which  supports  TIOCGWINSZ or WIOCGETD, the window system's idea of the screen size takes precedence over the LINES and COLUMNS environment variables.

How to view colourful logs with `less`?

**Resoved before asked**: `less -SR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`less -SR` will make less interpret colour sequences explicitly and will fix "-S".